# Does the following hold for every $i\in \mathbb{N} $ : $\sum_{k=0}^{i} a^{k}=\frac{a^{i+1}-1}{a-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I know that for $ |a| < 1$  the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{k} = \frac{1}{1-a}$

But I don't know this equation and whether it holds for every $i\in \mathbb{N} $

---

$\sum_{k=0}^{i} a^{k}=\frac{a^{i+1}-1}{a-1}$

---

Comment: [Geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum).

Comment: @nejimban but what would r be in my case?

Comment: $r=a$ in your case (with the $a$ of Wikipedia equal to $1$)

Comment: @nejimban so this formula wont work for any a in $\mathbb{N}$ as a != 1 is required...

Comment: Yes and you are assuming $|a|<1$. Anyway the sum is quite easy to compute when $a=1$.

Comment: Multiply $(a - 1) \times \left(a^k + a^{k-1} + \cdots + a + 1\right),$ and examine the product closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a proof of this identity, let us start by defining $S_i = \sum_{k=0}^{i} a^k = 1 + a + a^2 + \cdots + a^i$. We then multiply both sides by $a$ to get $aS_i = a + a^2 + a^3 + \cdots + a^{i+1}$. Then we subtract these two terms from eachother which will cancel out a lot of terms, this gives $S_i - aS_i = 1 - a^{i+1}$. Take out a factor $S_i$ on the LHS and divide by $1 - a$ to get that:
$$
s = \frac{1 - a^{i+1}}{1 - a} = \sum_{k=0}^{i} a^k
$$
Which can be shown to be equivalent to your definition.

Comment: But is this true for any $a,i\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the arguments presented aren't reliant on the values of $a$ or $i$.

Comment: thank you mate.